# how to separate and show data from one column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem splitting single column values to multiple column values.

On this:

```
Name
------------
Tom Howard
Michael Black
Wiliam Cruise
Bet Moor
```

I need the output something like this:

```
first_name          last_name
------------------------------
Tom                  Howard
Michael              Black
Wiliam               Cruise
Bet                  Moor
```

I have to show data(last_name) from one column(name).
Thank you

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works.

Comment: @ReInfo_91 Please show which answer works so that the community knows what worked for you.

Comment: Sorry, this answer (from John Cappelletti): Select Name
      ,first_name=Substring(Name,1,charindex(' ',name)-1)
      ,last_name =Substring(Name,charindex(' ',name)+1,50)
 From @YourTable

Comment: select Name, left (Name,charindex(' ', Name)-1) as first_name, right(Name,charindex(' ', reverse(Name))-1) as last_name from Table.   This also works with small change(reverse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your version, you could use PARSENAME() or Substring()

```
Declare @YourTable table (Name varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
('Tom Howard'),
('Michael Black'),
('Wiliam Cruise'),
('Bet Moor')

Select Name
      ,first_name=PARSENAME(Replace(Name,' ','.'),2)
      ,last_name =PARSENAME(Replace(Name,' ','.'),1)
 From @YourTable

-- OR --

Select Name
      ,first_name=Substring(Name,1,charindex(' ',name)-1)
      ,last_name =Substring(Name,charindex(' ',name)+1,50)
 From @YourTable
```

Returns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the left and right function to find these items pretty quickly:

```
select Name, left(Name,charindex(' ',Name)-1) as first_name, right(Name,charindex(' ',Name)-1) as last_name from yourtable
```

As long as you have a single space in the Name field this should work fine, if you have more than one space then you will lose any data that is between the spaces.